# Error on apache start: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_scgi.load

Tags: apache

In ubuntu server when I try to start apache it gives following error message.

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_scgi.load: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

What is the reason for the error? And how can I get through this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by enabling the `proxy_scgi` module. Following is the command to enable the module in linux.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_scgi
```